# Plist contains the "&" character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I'm having a .plist file which has some values with the "&" sign, for example "M&I". When I save the file to the document folder and load it from there, I'm getting an empty dictionary. Any idea to how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are directly modifying the XML file, you have to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) certain characters - `&` should be escaped using the XML entity `&amp;`. If you use the editors, this should be done automatically for you.

If you use [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) sections instead, you don't have to escape the characters.

Comment: i'm directly  modifying the xml                                    <Code>                                                                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key><![CDATA[a&amp;b]]></key>
  <array>
   <string><![CDATA[a&amp;b]]></string>
   <string>zip path</string>
   <string>zip name</string>
   <string>date</string>
  </array>
 </dict>
</plist>                                                      </Code>                                                            but im  getting an empty dictionary when read the list,

Comment: even if i remove the CDATA i can't read the data to dictionary,when i remove the "&" everything works fine.

Comment: @Sam: Actually that loads for me. You only need to use either `CDATA` or escapes though.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the values when open plist file as property list it would do it automatically.